# What does "plagiaristic and marred by obvious suppressions" mean?

Tags: meaning

> "for the intimate revelations of young men, or at least the terms in which they express them, are usually plagiaristic and marred by obvious suppressions." (The Great Gatsby, Chapter 1)

Intimate revelations are secrets. How can a secret be plagiarized? When the narrator says "marred by obvious suppressions," I'm assuming he is saying that these men aren't truthfully expressing their secrets. But I'm confused on the word choice. What exactly is being suppressed?

Comment: They're "secrets" might be less than candid, i.e., what they've heard *other* young men have confessed, and omitting they're own *faux pas* and faults.

Comment: 'The terms in which they express them' - they may speak of their own past in language copied from books - and suppress the more embarrassing details.

Answer (score 1):

The terms used to express intimate “revelations” are “plagiaristic”, in that they are simply repeated terms and not true revelations.
“Marred by obvious suppressions” means they are not truly expressing their complete feelings. It is easy to see they are not sharing all of their secrets.

Answer (score 0):

> for the intimate revelations of young men,

That is when young men talk about their sex life

> or at least the terms in which they express them

That is the words that they use to talk about sex

> are usually plagiaristic

Young men copy the stories that other young men tell about sex.

> and marred by obvious suppressions

And they don't tell the whole story when they have failed in some way

---

Basically when young men talk about sex they boast, by copying other men, and they don't talk about their failures.